# Unable to create Springboot connection with Postgres using SSL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, ssl

**Exception is thrown while making connection to Postgres using SSL.**

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert:
> unexpected_message    at
> sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)  at
> sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)  at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)     at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1127)    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
> at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41)  ... 57 common
> frames omitted

Comment: Do you have access to the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files?  What client are you using to connect?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem. We need to convert sslkey to .pk8 format properly.

Connection string:

```html
jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<db>?currentSchema=public&ssl=true&sslmode=verify-full&sslcert=<path>/server.crt&sslkey=<path>/server.pk8&sslrootcert=<path>/ca.crt

Where <path> refers to certs location.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the connection's driver settings to include the 'sslmode' parameter and setting it to 'require'.

You may also need to add a 'sslrootcert' parameter, setting it to the full file path of the root CA certificate on your local machine.

For a SpringBoot connection, this usually means specifying these as in-line with the database URI wherever you have it (in application.properties, etc.), i.e. appending the above to the connection URI as such:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>?ssl=true&sslmode=require&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.DefaultJavaSSLFactory
```